# Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I am asked to show that the splitting field of $X^4-6X^2+4$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$. By solving the quartic polynomial, I showed that the splitting field of this polynomial is in fact $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})$. So my question is if these two fields are equal to each other and if so how.

Comment: One thing to notice is that this polynomial does not vanish at $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$...

Comment: No, the fields are not equal, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043830/determine-the-minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt-3-sqrt-5). There might be a typo, so that $X^4-16X^2+4$ was meant.

Comment: @DietrichBurde OK, so that polynomial isn't the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$.  That doesn't immediately imply that $\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$ generates a different field than $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ does.

Comment: @anonymous Both have degree $4$

Comment: If my calculations are correct, $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{10})$.  So, you can show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5})$, whose intermediate quadratic fields are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$.  But $\sqrt{15} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5})$, so...

Comment: Exactly! I was also sensing that there might be a typo in the question. Either the polynomial was supposed to be $X^2-16X+4$ or they wrote the square root wrongly.

Comment: @DanielSchepler yes you are right. Actually the following question is to find intermediate fields by using Galois theory and I also found the same fields.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Great Observations!

Comment: We don't need the intermediate quadratic fields in order to conclude that $\sqrt3\notin\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt5)$. It's just a matter of calculation with radicals.

Comment: The fields are not equal and one can prove that $\sqrt{3}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})$ using the technique applied in this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304716/72031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments, let me mention that the usual exercise is to find the splitting field of $X^4-16X^2+4$. It is given by $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$,
see here:

[Determine the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043830/determine-the-minimal-polynomial-of-sqrt-3-sqrt-5).

However, if really $X^4-6X^2+4$ was meant, then the splitting field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})$. It is easy to see that
$\sqrt{2}\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}})$, but $\sqrt{2}$ is not contained in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ - see here:

[How to show that $\sqrt{2}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169315/how-to-show-that-sqrt2-is-not-in-mathbb-q-sqrt3-sqrt5)

So the fields given in the title are not equal.